# Squish set application context to aut started by aut under test

Tags: python, qt, squish

In python, is it possible to set application context to the second gui which is invoked by the GUI under test.

Ex: We start an application called `test1.exe` using `startApplication`. Clicking a button in `text1.exe` GUI invokes another  GUI application called `test2.exe`.

Now is it possible to set application context to `test2.exe` GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Squish for Qt requires that the sub-process be started by ***squish_dir/bin/startaut.exe*** (then use ***attachToApplication()***), *squish_dir/bin/dllpreload.exe* (automatic hookup), or have the built-in hook compiled into it.

In some cases you may get away by doing the following (documented in [Additional Setup for Hooking up Qt Sub-Processes on Windows Non-Invasively](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rghsa-sub.html#rg.squish.for.qt.sub.processes.on.windows.non.invasively)):

- Rename ***test2.exe*** to ***test2_.exe***
- Copy ***squish_for_qt_dir/bin/dllpreload.exe*** into the same folder as ***test2_.exe*** and rename it to ***test2.exe***.

This way ***test1.exe*** will invoke ***test2.exe***, which is now ***dllpreload.exe*** in "disguise", which will cause that ***dllpreload.exe*** to start ***test2_.exe***.

This approach will not work if ***test1.exe*** requires the process ID of ***test2.exe***, or if ***test2.exe*** requires the process ID of its parent process, because in both cases that is the renamed ***dllpreload.exe***. This will also not work if ***test1.exe*** and ***test2_.exe*** try to communicate with each other via their stdout, stderr, stdin streams (because ***dllpreload.exe*** does not set this up).

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting 'Hook in to sub-processes...' in the test suite settings.